# Count how many times a word appears per group of strings

Tags: python

**I have this code below and I would to find how it can be re-written to be more efficient (i.e. faster and more readable)**, given also that my actual vocabulary consists of 100k words and not 17 as below.

The goal is to count from a list of strings how many times (as a percentage) a word appears per group of these strings.

So for example at the descriptions below the word `elections` appears in 50% of the `Politics` group and in 0% of the `Economics` group.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from collections import Counter
import time

start_time = time.time()

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer="word", ngram_range=(1, 1), min_df=5)
vectorizer.fit(bank_descriptions)
vocabulary = vectorizer.vocabulary_
vocabulary = list(vocabulary.keys())

labels_counts = dict(Counter(labels))
unique_labels = list(labels_counts.keys())
unique_labels_indexes = {label:index for index, label in enumerate(unique_labels)}
labels_number = len(unique_labels)

words_dict = {}
words_dict_count = {}
for word in vocabulary:
    words_dict[word] = [0] * labels_number
    words_dict_count[word] = [0] * labels_number

for index, description in enumerate(bank_descriptions):

    for word in description.split():

        word = word.lower()
        if word in vocabulary:
            current_label = labels[index]
            label_index = unique_labels_indexes[current_label]
            words_dict_count[word][label_index] += 1
            words_dict[word][label_index] = words_dict_count[word][label_index] / labels_counts[current_label]

# words_dict should look like: {'new': [1.0, 0], 'elections': [0.5, 0], 'are': [0.5, 0], 'scheduled': [0.5, 0], 'for': [0.5, 0], '2023': [0.5, 0], 'the': [0.5, 1.0], 'unemployment': [0, 1.0], 'is': [0, 1.0], 'rising': [0, 1.0], 'prime': [0.5, 0], 'minister': [0.5, 0], 'worked': [0.5, 0], 'as': [0.5, 0], 'software': [0.5, 0], 'engineer': [0.5, 0], 'before': [0.5, 0]}


end_time = time.time()
print('Time:', round(end_time - start_time, 3), 'seconds')
```

Comment: One way to make things faster is to speed up the search for words, you can do that by splitting the strings into individual words and loading them into a binary tree data structure.

Comment: A specific coding answer is welcome @HasanAli ;)

Comment: One minor speedup would be to only calculate `words_dict[word][label_index] = words_dict_count[word][label_index] / labels_counts[current_label]` once at the end, rather than after every update

Comment: Another small one, `vocabulary = list(vocabulary.keys())` can just be omitted

Comment: One that might be faster or slower would be to skip the indexes and work directly with dicts; you'd have to try (unless you already have and this way is faster)

Answer (score 0):

Can you test and see if this code is faster? I basically removed `CountVectorizer()` since you are only using it to get the unique words of the `descriptions`, instead, I added all the words of the `descriptions` to a set data structure which gives us unique words.

```py
from collections import Counter
import time

start_time = time.time()

descriptions = ['New elections are scheduled for 2023', 'The unemployment is rising',
                ' The new Prime Minister worked as a software engineer before']
labels = ['Politics', 'Economics', 'Politics']

# descriptions *= int(1e3)
# labels *= int(1e3)

vocabulary = set()
for description in descriptions:
    for word in description.split():
        vocabulary.add(word)
print(vocabulary)

labels_counts = dict(Counter(labels))
unique_labels = list(labels_counts.keys())
unique_labels_indexes = {label:index for index, label in enumerate(unique_labels)}
labels_number = len(unique_labels)
print(unique_labels_indexes)

words_dict = {}
words_dict_count = {}
for word in vocabulary:
    words_dict[word] = [0] * labels_number
    words_dict_count[word] = [0] * labels_number

for index, description in enumerate(descriptions):

    for word in description.split():

        word = word.lower()
        if word in vocabulary:
            label_index = unique_labels_indexes[labels[index]]
            words_dict_count[word][label_index] += 1
            words_dict[word][label_index] = words_dict_count[word][label_index] / labels_counts[labels[index]]


print(words_dict)
end_time = time.time()
print('Time:', round(end_time - start_time, 3), 'seconds')
```

Comment: Thank you Hasan! Yeah I can but to start with I want to have the percentages per "group" (Politics, Economics) for every word in the vocabulary. At your code you only do for 'elections' and 'Politics'. You should have something like the 'words_dict' I printed at my post. PS It is interesting how a relatively "easy" task requires quite a lot of coding.

Comment: ok let me edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you Hasan :). Your code is quite a lot more well structured but it is actually 30-50% slower than mine and the more you increase the data the bigger the difference. I just did `descriptions * int(1e6)` and `labels * int(1e6)` and I noticed that. (Although I should also test with more different groups/labels than just 2.

Comment: interesting, I guess it might be the functions slowing down the program, you could try to remove the functions and use the lines directly, also, using numpy arrays instead of python lists could help.

Comment: Haha ok; feel free to modify your code. It is more difficult for me to understand it. Also not sure it will actually make things much faster. May be anyway there is nothing much better in comparison to what I written (although I wrote this code above without thinking much about it and anyway usually I do not write the most optimal code haha).

Comment: another idea could be to use `CountVectorizer()` and save its results then use a faster programming language to process the results.

Comment: Yeah could be but I am not very familiar with any other language. :(

Comment: I think my `label_index = unique_labels.index(labels[index])` should be certainly done (at least partly) outside the nested for loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241631/discussion-between-outcast-and-hasan-ali).